# (More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/CHANGES') error on android studio after adding jsoup.jar file

Tags: android, jsoup

I added **jsoup.jar** file each two way

first is file -> projectstructure -> import jar/.aar package -> add jardepedency
and it failed build with the error message.

and I tried another way that is add jar file to app -> libs -> rightclick to jar file -> add as library.

and it failed at build too.

I tried googling and find way

```
116
down vote
You can add this in yourProject/app/build.gradle inside android{}

android {

      packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
      }

    }
```

this
but still failed
all i did on my project is add jsoup library.
i don't know why it fails at build 
anyone know why?

https://github.com/minyouminyou/errorAndroid
this is my project github 
thanks :>

- i download json.jar file at official site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message concerns `META-INF/CHANGES` but your list of excluded files doesn't contain it.

Add this line:

```
    exclude 'META-INF/CHANGES'
```

Comment: it works!! thanks :>!! and after i added that ccode, "'META-INF/README.md' ...something "message loged, so i added about it too

Comment: If it helped, you should [mark the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).